# Cinnamon + Gnome = Ignored settings?

Tags: fedora, gnome3, settings, cinnamon

I recently switched from Gnome to Cinnamon in Fedora 17, and I feel like I did something wrong because it seems as though Cinnamon ignores any Gnome settings, despite being Gnome-based (as far as I understand it). All of the help pages I come across suggest using gconf-editor, dconf-editor, or even the "keyboard settings" to change settings such as the compose key, hotkeys, or the alt+click behavior, but cinnamon ignores anything I change in any of these. I've had to resort to using xbindkeys and running that in a .rc file on startup for hotkeys.

It also seems to ignore anything I put into gnome-session-properties to try to run on startup.

Does anyone know why Cinnamon seems to run just fine but ignore all gnome settings?

Thanks

Comment: These should all work. If you run gnome-session-properties and make changes, do those changes persist on the next invocation of gnome-session-properties? (well, do the changes show up in the gnome-session-properties app regardless of whether or not they seem to be happening?) If you make changes in the cinnamon-settings app, do those persist across sessions?

Comment: It seems as though nothing in gnome-session-properties even runs. Changes persist, but they don't actually do anything. The cinnamon-settings app does work for most things (panels, menu, etc), but not keyboard shortcuts for some reason, though those also persist.

Comment: Well.... check ~/.xsession-errors (expecially the top of the file). Something's blowing up silently when you first log in and causing most everything else gnome specific to fail/not start after that. Cinnamon is just a shell program running on top of gnome 3 (as is gnome-shell). The cinnamon specific things that are working are... specific to cinnamon, but the keyboard short-cuts are actually part of gnome3.

Comment: It looks like a lot of the things that gnome-session-properties didn't seem to be running are trying to run and failing, but for different reasons. The only settings-related thing I see is: "(cinnamon-settings.py:8186): Gtk-WARNING **: Attempting to set the permissions of `/home/me/.local/share/recently-used.xbel', but failed: Operation not permitted" because I disabled that. Is it now a necessary component for getting functioning settings?

Comment: @vityav, look at any files mentioned like the message you cite: Does it exist? What are the permissions on each of the components of the path leading to it? What does the file conntain?

Comment: I specifically made that an empty file with no write permission so the system wouldn't keep suggesting "recently used" files to me. I just didn't think it would break any system settings, but if that's not true in cinnamon, I'll change it back.